# Game does not launch from Menu

Tags: c++, sfml, game-development

I am new to Game Development. I managed to create a simple game (like Space Invaders) as well as a simple start Menu using C++ and SFML. **However, upon pressing "Enter" on the main menu, the game is not being launched.** How do I link it properly? I appreciate your help. This is not homework.

main.cpp codes

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include "GameObjectManager.h"
#include "Menu.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    sf::Texture galaxyBackgroundTexture;
    sf::Sprite galaxyBackground;
    if (!galaxyBackgroundTexture.loadFromFile("Textures/galaxybackground.png")) {
        cout << "Failed to load Image" << endl;
    }

    galaxyBackground.setTexture(galaxyBackgroundTexture);
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1200, 800), "Space Invader Test");
    Menu menu(window.getSize().x, window.getSize().y);

    window.setFramerateLimit(144);
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;

        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Key::Return)
            {
                menu.GetPressedItem();
                cout << "Play button has been pressed." << endl;
                GameObjectManager* gameObjectManagerManager = new GameObjectManager(&window);
                gameObjectManager->update();
                gameObjectManager->render(window);
            }
            else if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();
            }
            else if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)
            {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(galaxyBackground);
        menu.draw(window);
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Menu.h

```
#pragma once
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#define MAX_NUMBER_OF_ITEMS 2

class Menu
{
public:
    Menu(float width, float height);
    ~Menu();

    void draw(sf::RenderWindow& window);
    int GetPressedItem() { return selectedItemIndex; }


private: 
    int selectedItemIndex;
    sf::Font font;
    sf::Text menu[MAX_NUMBER_OF_ITEMS];    
};
```

Menu.cpp

```
#include "Menu.h"
Menu::Menu(float width, float height)
{
    if (!font.loadFromFile("arial.ttf"))
    {
        cout << "can't load font" << endl;
    }

    // initialise Menu items
    menu[0].setFont(font);
    menu[0].setColor(sf::Color::Red);
    menu[0].setString("Play");
    menu[0].setPosition(sf::Vector2f(width / 2, height / (MAX_NUMBER_OF_ITEMS + 1) * 1));

    // EXIT
    menu[1].setFont(font);
    menu[1].setColor(sf::Color::White);
    menu[1].setString("Exit");
    menu[1].setPosition(sf::Vector2f(width / 2, height / (MAX_NUMBER_OF_ITEMS + 1) * 2));
}
selectedItemIndex = 0;

Menu::~Menu()
{
}

void Menu::draw(sf::RenderWindow &window)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_ITEMS; i++)
    {
        window.draw(menu[i]);
    }
}
```

The console window would print:

```
"Play button has been pressed"
```

But it does not proceed to the game. Nothing else happens.

Comment: "without using states". I'd almost automatically use a state for this. Might be just a bool but still. Any particular reason you don't want to?

Comment: What about polymorphism? I use it a lot to seperate the menu from gameplay when working on projects. You could have a `gameplay` class and `menu` class, both inheriting an abstract `scene` class with pure virtual functions like `update()` and `render()`. Then have both scene objects alive at all times and `scene` pointer to one of those scenes, or have the `scene` pointer manage the memory of the current scene, perhaps using `std::unique_ptr`. The former you would change scenes like `scene = &gameplay` to switch to gameplay, the latter you would use `scene = std::make_unique<gameplay>()`.

Comment: `'window': redefinition; multiple initialization` means you are making the window in two different places; on line 15 and line 40 of `main.cpp`. You can have two windows, they just need different variable names, or you can use the same window by replacing line 40 with changing the window size, title, etc. `'sf::Text::setColor': was declared deprecated` means that this function has been removed from SFML. SFML's documentation states "There is now fill and outline colors instead of a single global color. Use `setFillColor()` or `setOutlineColor()` instead."

Comment: @Lily Hi Lily, thank you for your detailed explanation. It has certainly helped me learn more about SFML. The errors have been solved as well. Currently, the game does not launch after pressing "Play" on the main menu. I am thinking it is some linkage problem in my main.cpp file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"window redefinition" error occurs because both your RenderWindow objects have the same identifiers (i.e. window). You might want to change the name of the second window or better yet use the same window.

The second error, `sf::Text::setColor()` is deprecated means that it is no longer "useable" or "is not suggested to be used". SFML has two new better functions for this:

`sf::Text::setFillColor()` : to set the fill of your text.

`sf::Text::setOutlineColor()` : to give your text an outline (you also need to do change the thickness using `setOutlineThickness()`).

Moreover, I'd suggest you to use a State Machine for different scenes instead of two separate windows. It really isn't that difficult and will help you learn a few more things. You're somewhat already achieving this with your gameObjectManager. You just need to abstract it and implement it for your menu class as well. And since you have only two scenes you can simply use an integer or boolean to switch between these two.

EDIT: an idea of what you need to do to your main.cpp file

```
int main()
{
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1200, 800), "Space Invader Test");
GameObjectManager* gameObjectManagerManager = nullptr;
bool inGame = false; //true = game has started, false = menu screen

while (window.isOpen())//this is the main loop
{
    sf::Event event;

    while (window.pollEvent(event)) //this is the event loop
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Key::Return) 
        {
            if(!inGame)
            { 
                if(menu.GetPressedItem() == PlayButton) //assuming your function returns which button in the menu has been pressed
                {
                    cout << "Play button has been pressed." << endl;
                    inGame = true;
                    gameObjectManagerManager = new GameObjectManager(&window);
                }
                else 
                {
                    window.close(); //since the other button is exit
                }
            }
        }
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) window.close();
        
        if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape) window.close();
        
    }
    
    //this is the place where you call your updates
    if(inGame) gameObjectManagerManager->update();

    window.clear();
    window.draw(galaxyBackground);
    
    if(!inGame)menu.draw(window);

    if(inGame) gameObjectManagerManager->render();

    window.display();
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. Certainly helped to clarify my doubts and learn more about SFML. I managed to solved the errors and get the Main Menu up and running. However, it does not let me proceed to the game upon pressing enter (play) on the main menu. I am thinking it is a linkage problem on the main.cpp. I have updated the question as well. Thank you.

Comment: That is because you're calling your update and render functions only once, that too in the event loop only when enter key is pressed. Your update needs to be outside the event loop and you render between the 'window.clear()' and 'window.display()' function. Moreover you are not checking which state you are in. Is it the menu? or the game? I have updated the answer with a hint to what you must do.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest you try to get a better understanding of what states or scenes are before proceeding. Also, learn a bit about how game loops and events work. There are a lot of good resources available on the internet.

Comment: are you able to help out with [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66849716/background-image-not-displaying-on-main-menu-screen)