# Background Image overlapping Main Menu Items

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml, game-development

I just started learning Game Development recently. I managed to develop a simple game (something like Space Shooters) and a simple start menu using C++ and SFML. *(THIS IS NOT HOMEWORK)*

**Problem: The background image for the Main Menu screen overlaps my text/menu items. But the background image for the Game Screen does not overlap my game items.**

Relevant codes:
main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    //Background Image for Game Screen
    sf::Texture galaxyBackgroundTexture, menuBackgroundTexture;
    sf::Sprite galaxyBackground, menuBackground;
    sf::Vector2u TextureSize;  //Added to store texture size.
    sf::Vector2u WindowSize;   //Added to store window size.

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1200, 800), "Space Invader Team 62");

    if (!galaxyBackgroundTexture.loadFromFile("Textures/galaxy_background.png"))
    {
        cout << "Failed to load Image" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        TextureSize = galaxyBackgroundTexture.getSize(); //Get size of texture
        WindowSize = window.getSize();             //Get size of window

        float ScaleX = (float)WindowSize.x / TextureSize.x;
        float ScaleY = (float)WindowSize.y / TextureSize.y;     //Calculate scale

        galaxyBackground.setTexture(galaxyBackgroundTexture);
        galaxyBackground.setScale(ScaleX, ScaleY);      //Set scale
    }


    // Menu
    menuBackground.setTexture(menuBackgroundTexture);
    Menu menu(window.getSize().x, window.getSize().y);
    GameObjectManager* gameObjectManagerManager = nullptr;

    bool inGame = false; //true = game has started, false = menu screen

    //  window.setFramerateLimit(144);
    while (window.isOpen()) // main loop
    {
        sf::Event event;

        while (window.pollEvent(event)) // event loop
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Key::Return)
            {
                if (!inGame)
                {
                    cout << "Play button has been pressed." << endl;
                    inGame = true;
                    gameObjectManagerManager = new GameObjectManager(&window);
                }
            }
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) window.close();

            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape) window.close();

        }

        //this is the place where you call your updates
        if (inGame) gameObjectManagerManager->update();

        window.clear();

        if (!inGame)menu.draw(window);
        {
            window.draw(menuBackground);
        }

        if (inGame)
        {
            window.draw(galaxyBackground);
            gameObjectManagerManager->render(window);
        }

        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your background image is drawn after the items. You need to draw them in the correct order.
Change this:

```
if (!inGame)menu.draw(window);
    {
        window.draw(menuBackground);
    }
```

TO THIS:

```
if (!inGame)
    {
        window.draw(menuBackground);
        menu.draw(window);
    }
```